# Solving a complex integral using only the definition

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm struggling to solve such an integral using only the definition of the integral of complex function, any hints?

$$
\int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{z^2+4iz}.
$$

contour $\gamma$ is a triangle with vertices -1+2i, -1-2i and 1

Comment: Can you tell us that exact definition which shoud be used?

Comment: This means that I shouldn't use Newton-Leibniz formula or Cauchy formula, just plain integration

Comment: It's hopeless without at least the Newton-Leibniz..

Comment: Well, unless there's some rather nice trick I'm missing, trying to do this integral by means of parametrization and line integrals is going to be a huge pain in the mathematical gland.

Comment: Could someone describe the solution process when using the Newton-Leibniz formula? How to decide which Ln branch to choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Cauchy's Residue theorem: since the function $\,\displaystyle{f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+4iz}}\,$ only has the pole $\,z=0\,$ inside the domain enclosed by the triangle's perimeter and the function's analytic over the perimeter, we get

$$Res_{z=0}(f)=\lim_{z\to 0}zf(z)=\frac{1}{4i}\Longrightarrow\int_\gamma\frac{dz}{z^2+4iz}=2\pi i\frac{1}{4i}=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

If by "definition" you meant the line integrals on the different sides of the triangles then that's way too cumbersome and lengthy (at least for me)